# How to change DHCP ip address range in VMware fusion?

Tags: ip, dhcp, vmware-fusion

I want to change dhcp ip address range in VMware fusion for example by default the pool start with 192.168.0.128 and ends with 192.168.0.254 
and i want to change that to 192.168.0.203 - 192.168.0.254, so please help on how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the Virtual Network that you are using, you can customize it based on your needs.

Comment: Ok, but how that's the question.

Comment: check this for more info: https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-C5837B81-9509-4F1B-9572-0EC0CFA87563.html

Comment: This link does not provide a solution to my problem. but thanks